# GitHub Organization Pages without named repository

Tags: html, css, git, github, github-pages

Is it possible to create a website for a GitHub Organization (using GitHub Pages) without creating a repository with the same name?

As an example, for the organization `CompPyrol`, I created a repository that has the same name as the organization as `comppyrol.github.io`.  The html and css files for the website are located in this repository.  So the website for the organization is located at `http://comppyrol.github.io`.  This works but I was hoping to use GitHub pages for an organization without having to create a repository just for the website.  I know you can create an orphaned branch `gh-pages` for the web files but that seems to be for an individual repository or project, not for an entire organization page.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. GitHub's [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) is quite clear:

> ### User & Organization Pages
>
> **User & Organization Pages** live in a special repository dedicated to GitHub Pages files. You will need to name this repository with the
>   account name, e.g.
>   [atmos/atmos.github.io](https://github.com/atmos/atmos.github.io)
>
> - You must use the `username/username.github.io` naming scheme.
> - Content from the `master` branch will be used to build and publish your GitHub Pages site.

**Update:**

GitHub Pages used to be served as subdomains of github.*com*, but [switched to github.*io* in April, 2013](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io). Some repositories are still set up using the old naming, but are now hosted on the new domain:

> Changes to GitHub repositories:
>
> - User Pages repositories may now be named using the new **username/username.github.io** convention or the older **username/username.github.com** convention.
> - Existing User Pages repositories named like **username/username.github.com** do not need to be renamed and will continue to be published indefinitely.
> - If both a **username.github.io** and a **username.github.com** repository exists, the **username.github.io** version wins.

Comment: Well, I was looking at this organization page http://collective.github.io but I couldn't find an associated repository listed in the organization at https://github.com/collective

Comment: @Gavin, the repository for that site is actually at https://github.com/collective/collective.github.com (note the .com instead of .io). Please see my updated answer for details.

Comment: Oh I see. I wasn't aware of the old `github.com` subdomains. That explains why I wasn't seeing a `github.io` repo for some organizations. Thanks!